# Error E2040 when compiling

Tags: c

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kInv1.png)I'm fairly new to the community and would appreciate the input to an error i've encountered. I was wondering want is causing the error when i compile.

Thank You, 
Josh

```
#include<stdio>

int main();
{
    char name;
    printf("Enter your name:");
    scanf("%c", &name);

    print("Hello, your name is %c", name);

    getch(); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Format your code properly, and include the exact error message

Comment: `stdio` should be `stdio.h`, and you may also need another header for `getch` which is a non-standard function. (In fact removing `getch();` entirely would be a good solution)

Comment: @M.M Thank you for the response, i removed getch();  also included "#include<conio.h> and added the #include <stdio.h> but again received the error.

Comment: remove the ; after int main(), also there's nothing called print in C. Try printf

Comment: Why are you using Borland 5.5?  That compiler hasn't been updated in 15 years.  Go get the [free version of Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/) or [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) if you want to learn C programming.

Answer (score 0):

Two bugs:

This is the source of your compile error:

```
print("Hello, your name is %c", name);
```

It needs to be `printf`, not `print`

Second, it will only print the first character of the input name.  you need to use a char array (string) and the %s format specifier.

```
int main();
{
    char name[300];
    printf("Enter your name:");
    scanf("%299s", name);
    name[299] = '\0';

    printf("Hello, your name is %s\n", name);

    getch(); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fixed.  But you should know that for arrays declared on the stack, `&name == name` is a true expression.

Comment: `&name == name` is a constraint violation - your compiler should give a diagnostic message if you try it

Comment: Hmm... that didn't use to be the case years ago..... but it's all for the better.

Answer (score 0):

Error E2040 is caused when a declaration has an extra or incorrect termination symbol, such as a semicolon placed after a function body.

You have placed a semicolon after `int main()`. Remove that and get your syntax right, you'll be all good.

Comment: THANK YOU SOOOO MUCH!!! For everyones feedback, I removed the  semicolon after int main , i replaced print with printf, and changed from %d to %s and it worked. I appreciate everyone patience. This is new to me.

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue as what it is you are trying to achieve  but anyways.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  int main( ) 
  {

  char c[100];

  printf( "Enter your name :");
  gets( c );

  printf( "\nHello your name is : ");
  puts( c );

 return 0;
```

}